# Unknown icon using Jboss Studio + svn

Tags: svn, eclipse-plugin, jboss-developer-studio

I'm using Jboss Studio + the SVN plugin. 
This morning I compared a local java package with a previous revision. I noticed this unknown icon: 
[image]

Does anyone know its meaning?

Many thanks!

Comment: FYI: JBoss is based on Eclipse and is using Subclipse plug-in for SVN integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon means that there are incoming changes to this file. I.e. when you run `svn update` the file will get some changes from the repository.

It's an analog of [`svn status --show-updates`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.status.html) that will show an asterisk `*` in case there are incoming changes:

> '*' A newer revision of the item exists on the server.